# Checking a monitor's power status from a .net managed application

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I need to check if the power of a display/monitor (is it ON or OFF ?).

I've tried with WMI, using the Win32_DesktopMonitor and check the "Availability", but the value returned is always 3 (powered on), even when the monitor is physically turned off.

Now, looking at a few threads here on StackOverflow, there's one direction I'd like to follow and it's the use of IMSVidDevice Interface, but I have no clue how to use it.

I have this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd694527(v=vs.85).aspx to start.

It talks about using segment.h and segment.idl.  There's also the mention of msvidctl.h.

I found an MS Video Control 1.0 Type Library which seems to be what I'm looking for (it has an IMSVidDevice interface defined) but I can't figure out how to use this library.

```
        var devices = new MSVidCtlLib.MSVidOutputDevices();

        Console.WriteLine("Found {0} devices", devices.Count);

        foreach (MSVidCtlLib.IMSVidOutputDevice dev in devices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} - {2}", dev.Name, dev.Status, dev.Power);
        }
```

But the devices.count is always zero.  I have two monitors on my dev box.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one question per post, as the guidelines here say you should. If you post multiple questions, it's virtually impossible to accept a single response as being correct. For instance, if I post an answer to question #1, someone else answers #2, someone else answers #3, and yet another person answers #4, how do you decide which one to choose as the accepted answer? You can read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) if you want more information about what is (and isn't) a good question here. Thanks. :)

Comment: While you're in the FAQ reading about @KenWhite's comment you should read about signatures in questions.

Comment: I removed the extra questions, thanks

Comment: have you got the answer????

Comment: Hi, Neel, no answer.